# Herkunft, Genese und erste Nachweise von "drauf ankommen dass"

Tags: etymology

Jüngst wurde an diesem schönen Orte nach der Bedeutung von *drauf ankommen dass* gefragt.<sup>1</sup> Nun sind mir die Bedeutung und Verwendung der Phrase aus eigener Alltagspraxis vertraut genug. Die Phrase kommt vor in Sätzen wie:

> Beton - es kommt drauf an, was man draus macht.
>
> Lass es liegen, da kommt's jetzt auch nicht mehr drauf an.
>
> Ob ich Milch in den Kaffee will? Kommt drauf an, ob schon Zucker drin ist.
>
> Kommst du mit? - Das kommt drauf an...

Ein Synonym für die direkte Bedeutung wäre "Es hängt davon ab". In Alleinstellung wird es auch im Sinne von "Ich weiß noch nicht" verwendet.

So weit so gut.

Was ich nicht verstehe, ist die semantische Herkunft dieses Ausdrucks.

Gibt es Erklärungen, wie der Ausdruck sich semantisch zusammensetzt, oder wie es zu seiner Ausformung gekommen ist?

Und sprachgeschichtlich:

- Gibt es Nachweise zu seinem ersten Auftreten, etwa in mittelalterlichen oder frühneuzeitlichen Texten?
- Lässt sich eine realweltliche gängige Handlung, vielleicht im bäuerlichen Kulturkreis, finden, auf die diese Wendung zurückgeht?
- Oder eine Phrase aus einer der lateinischen Bibelfassungen, die dann ins Deutsche übertragen wurde?
- Kam ursprünglich mal konkret etwas (ein Ding) auf einer anderen Sache an? Der Vogel kam auf dem Zweig an? Steckt also irgend eine Geschichte oder Parabel dahinter, die früher jeder kannte?

Oder kurz: Was kommt auf was drauf, und wieso nicht nur drauf sondern auch an? <sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> [Ursprüngliche Frage nach der Bedeutung der Phrase](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/47171/kommt-es-dabei-gar-nicht-an)

<sup>2</sup> Ich überlege, ob ich diesen schönen Satz nicht als Überschrift hier nehmen soll. Wer dazu eine Meinung hat: Ich höre sie gerne!

---

**Kurzbericht aus der bisherigen Diskussion**

Angestoßen von der geistreichen Arbeit Jonathan Scholbachs (siehe unten) kam folgende Interpretation auf (die allerdings auch schon in Hubert Schölnasts Beitrag angelegt zu sein scheint):

*Drauf* ist möglicherweise gar nicht als räumliches *drauf* zu verstehen sondern als zeitliches, also wie *daraufhin*,  *in der Zukunft*, *nachfolgend*. Auch *ankommen* kann verstanden werden als zeitlich: als das Ankommen eines Ereignisses in der Gegenwart (nämlich kommend aus der Zukunft), oder kurz ganz einfach als *geschehen*. *Drauf ankommen* ist dann gleichbedeutend mit *nachfolgend geschehen*.

Dann wäre

> Ob wir morgen spazierengehen, kommt drauf an, wie's Wetter wird.

zu lesen als

> Unser Spazierengehen morgen findet statt, **nachdem** das Wetter aus der Zukunft angekommen ist (und wir entsprechend in der Lage sind, es einzuschätzen)

Nun wäre es natürlich schön, wir hätten noch einige Zitate aus Texten vergangener Jahrhunderte, wo diese semantische Wurzel noch deutlicher zutage tritt...

Comment: Hast du schon im Grimm und im Pfeifer nachgeschlagen?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach   Guter Hinweis. Leider sind diese Werke mir im Moment nicht zugänglich. Ein Besuch in der Stadtbibliothek könnte vielleicht helfen...

Comment: Nur als Tipp, weil es echt gute Ressourcen sind: Die sind beide auch online verfügbar: Grimm: dwb.uni-trier.de/de und Pfeifer: dwds.de

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach  Ach je, wie dumm von mir. Danke für die Erinnerung daran, dass wir im Elektronenzeitalter leben!

Comment: Übrigens, den Ausdruck gibt es auch im Niederländischen: "Er op aankomen" = "darauf ankommen", mit der gleichen Bedeutung. Und bedenke: in Englisch sagt man z.B. "to depend upon".

Comment: @RudyVelthuis   Niederländisch: sehr interessant! Das Englische "to depend upon" ist aber fehl am Platze hier. "Das hängt davon ab" gibt es auch im Deutschen, aber hier wollen wir ja ankommen, nicht abhängen. "That arrives upon..."?

Comment: @Christian: Na ja: "8. ⟨es kommt auf jmdn., etw. an⟩ es hängt von jmdm., etw. ab", siehe https://www.dwds.de/wb/ankommen. "Es kommt drauf an" = "Es hängt davon ab" = "It depends". Ich vermute, dass es schon was mit "If the event arrives" zu tun hat.

Comment: Übrigens, jetzige korrekte Schreibweise in Niederländisch ist "erop aankomen", nicht "er op aankomen".

Answer (score 10):

Weder Grimm [1] noch Pfeifer [2] noch Duden [3] geben hier eine Antwort. (Kluge und Wahrig habe ich jetzt nicht zur Hand, aber ich erwarte nicht, dass die hier detaillierter sind). Deswegen bin ich so frei, ein bisschen assoziativ zu spekulieren. Das ist nicht als erschöpfende Antwort gemeint, aber vielleicht kann es im Sinne einer Arbeitshypothese für Dritte ein Anstoß sein, in dieser Richtung weiter zu forschen.

Im Verb *ankommen* klingt für mich stark die Assoziation lateinisch `advenire` mit - was mich auf eine Assoziation im semantischen Feld des Zukünftigen verweist (schon das Wort *Zukunft* geht ja selbst auf *kommen* zurück.)

Adelung [4] nennt für *ankommen* als Bedeutung (c) *Das wirklich werden einer Sache erwarten [...]* und nennt dafür die Beispiele: *Er lässet es allemahl auf das Äußerste ankommen. Ich mag es auf seinen Ausspruch nicht ankommen lassen. Ein Thor lässet alles auf das Glück ankommen. Die kriegenden Parteyen wollen es auf ein Treffen ankommen lassen.* Unter (d) führt Adelung die Bedeutung *Den Grund von etwas enthalten, der Gegenstand eines Geschäftes seyn, [...].* an, die der hier diskutierten Bedeutung entspricht.

Meine Arbeitshypothese ist, dass die Bedeutung (d) als eine Übertragung der temporalen Bedeutung von (c) in eine kausale Bedeutung entstanden ist.

Hintergrund meiner Hypothese ist zunächst recht allgemein der Umstand, dass es eine sprachliche Analogie zwischen temporalen und kausalen Kategorien gibt, die sich etwa in der Etymologie einiger Konjunktionen (vgl. etwa die Etymologien von *weil* [5] und *denn* [6] oder die temporale und kausale Doppelbedeutung von engl. *since*) zeigt.

Außerdem ist meine Hypothese spezifischer dadurch motiviert, dass das Zukünftige grundsätzlich als ungewiss erlebt wird, und dass das Eintreten zukünftiger Ereignisse damit als eine Entscheidung erlebt werden kann. In dieser Konzeptualisierung ist das Fortschreiten der Zeit eine fortwährende Verengung des Möglichkeitsraums.

Es erscheint also möglich (und in meinen Augen wahrscheinlich), dass die Bedeutung `entscheidend sein` von *auf etwas ankommen* ein weiteres Beispiel für die genannte Analogie ist.

*Ich lasse Y auf X ankommen* würde sich also wörtlich als *Ich werde Y tun, nachdem (wenn) X eingetreten (angekommen) ist.* entschlüsseln. *auf* könnte hier die gleiche Bedeutung wie in *X folgt auf Y* haben, *Y kommt auf X (an)* wäre dann *Y folgt auf X*. (Dies illustriert freilich nur eine bloße Möglichkeit und scheint mir nicht per se ein starkes Argument für meine Arbeitshypothese zu sein.)

---

[1] *Ankommen*. In: Deutsches Wörterbuch von Jacob und Wilhelm Grimm. 1854-1961, http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GA04203#XGA04203

[2] *ankommen*. In: Wolfgang Pfeifer: Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen, 1989, https://www.dwds.de/wb/ankommen#et-1

[3] https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ankommen

[4] *Ankommen*. In: Johann Christoph Adelung: Grammatisch-Kritisches Wörterbuch der Hochdeutschen Mundart, 1793-1801, http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=Adelung&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=DA02340#XDA02340), hier (c)

[5] *weil*. In: Pfeifer: Etymologische Wörterbuch, https://www.dwds.de/wb/weil#et-1

[6] *denn*. In: Pfeifer: Etymologische Wörterbuch,  https://www.dwds.de/wb/denn#et-1

Comment: Ha! Deinen Ansatz weitertreibend, ausgehend von *advenire* sowie dem Aspekt des ungewissen Zukünftigen, das sich erst noch als Gegenwärtiges manifestieren muss: Möglicherweise ist "drauf" (oder "darauf") gar nicht zu verstehen als *räumliches* "darauf" sondern als *zeitliches*!  Dann wäre "Es kommt darauf an, dass" zu lesen als: "Es wird daraufhin werden" oder "Es wird erst in der Zukunft klarwerden, dass"...  Was perfekt in die Semantik passt!  (Mir kam dieser Gedanke beim Suchen nach lateinischen Wörtern für "darauf", und ich fand *deinde* = "dann, darauf, hierauf" --> *deinde advenit*...

Comment: Ich hatte diesen Gedanken eben auch und habe ihn ergänzt.

Comment: Die Hypothese testend: Der Dialog: "Kommst du mit? - Das kommt drauf an" ließe sich dann lesen als: "Kommst du  mit? - Das wird sich weisen". Passt! Die Frage nach dem Zucker im Kaffee: "Das wird sich weisen wenn klar ist, ob schon Milch drin ist." Passt!

Answer (score 5):

Alle Quellen, die ich konsultiert habe, verweisen bei *»ankommen«* nur auf *»kommen«*, und dort wird auf *»ankommen«* nur sehr beiläufig, und meist auch nur in der Bedeutung *»an einem Ort eintreffen«* behandelt. Trotzdem gebe ich hier mal meine gewonnenen Erkenntnisse wieder:

Das Verb *»kommen«* war Mittelhochdeutsch *»komen«*, Althochdeutsch *»queman«* und geht auf die indoeuropäische Wurzel **g<sup>u̯</sup>em-* zurück, das folgende Bedeutungen hatte:

- gehen
- kommen
- geboren werden (zur Welt kommen)

Aus dieser indoeuropäische Wurzel **g<sup>u̯</sup>em-* hat sich übrigens auch das Wort *»bequem«* entwickelt, aber auch das Substantiv *Kunft*, das heute nur noch in Zusammensetzungen wie *Ankunft, Auskunft, Einkunft, Unterkunft, Zukunft* usw. existiert, und davon abgeleitet das Adjektiv *»künftig«*.

Die Zusammensetzung *»**ankommen (komme an)**«* war:

- Mittelhochdeutsch: ***anekomen (kome an)*** = über einen kommen, hereinbrechen, anfangen, angreifen
- Althochdeutsch: ***anaqueman (chome ana)*** = über einen kommen, ergreifen, eintreffen, zu jemandem dringen

In einem [alten Wörterbuch](https://books.google.at/books?id=aJNEAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA172&lpg=PA172&dq=anaqueman&source=bl&ots=T9eg7Vk3MT&sig=XKBXQG3IBCp3VjhfeTg3a4UnzN0&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjI557cmtjdAhWhqIsKHSuPAp0Q6AEwBnoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=anaqueman&f=false) (Althochdeutsch - Latein) wird *anaqueman* mit folgenden lateinischen Vokabeln gleichgesetzt:

- venire (kommen)
- incidere (hineingeraten)
- insidere (sich niederlassen)
- ingredi (betreten, einmarschieren, hineingehen, sich einlassen auf etw.)
- subire (etw. auf sich nehmen, nahe herangehen, sich etw. unterziehen)
- obripere (jmdm. entgegenreisen, sich aufraffen)

Heute bedeutet *»**ankommen**«*:

- mit Wohlwollen aufnehmen

  > Deine Vorschlag ist beim Chef gut **angekommen.**
  >   Deine Vorschlag ist vom Chef mit Wohlwollen aufgenommen worden.
- eintreffen

  > Ich werde morgen in München **ankommen.**
  >   Ich werde morgen in München eintreffen.
- abhängen, bedingt sein

  > Es wird doch nicht auf die Farbe der Trikots **ankommen,** ob wir gewinnen.
  >   Es wird doch nicht von der Farbe der Trikots abhängen, ob wir gewinnen.

Mehr kann ich zu dieser sehr interessanten Frage leider nicht beitragen.

Comment: Die Auskünfte zu den ahd. und mhd. Vorläufern sind schon mal wichtig!

Comment: Eine Theorie von mir wäre, dass der Ursprung tatsächlich bei "ankommen" im Sinne von  "zusammenkommen" bzw. "an einem Ort eintreffen" liegt. Das Wort "auf" findet man auch in "auf Befehl von". Ein Herrscher z.B. kann "auf" seinen Befehl veranlassen, dass sich eine Gruppe Soldaten an einem Ort einfindet. Daraus könnte sich dann die Bedeutung "etwas kommt auf jemanden an" = "Ein Ereignis wird durch jemanden verursacht oder verhindert" entwickelt haben.

Comment: In der Bayerischen Mundart gibt es eine ähnliche Redewendung "da kommt's jetzt auch nimmer drauf zam" (= das ändert jetzt auch nichts mehr). Und "zamgehen" (zusammengehen) wird ebenfalls synonym mit "klappen" (z.B. ein Treffen) verwendet.

Comment: @Œlrim: Die in Österreich (ausgenommen Vorarlberg) gesprochenen Dialekte sind zwar auch bayrische Dialekte, aber zumindest im Osten Österreichs (Steiermark, Burgenland, Niederösterreich und Wien) wird »zamgehen« nicht in dem von dir genannten Sinn verwendet. Ich erinnere mich aber, dieses Wort in Filmen und Serien, die in Bayern spielen, in diesem Sinn gehört zu haben.

Comment: Zur Bedeutung "mit Wohlwollen aufnehmen": das Wohlwollen wird allerdings primär vom Wort "gut" ausgedrückt, der Vorschlag kann schließlich auch "schlecht ankommen".